# Which is the correct glyph origin of 入

Tags: etymology, glyph-origin

I find 2 very different glyph origins for 入

1. It shows the roots of a plant entering the ground.
2. It is a picture of an open tent or tent door.

Which is correct?

Comment: [說文新證](http://m.sanmin.com.tw/product/index/004732840) says that the etymology of the earliest oracle bone form of 入 is unclear. This book seems to be quite well-researched, which means that your question cannot be reliably answered. Most explanations you can see are guesses, and there's probably not enough information to say whose guess is more likely.

Comment: @Pedroski Where did you find these two "very different etymologies"?

Comment: zhongwen.com and chineseetymology.org

Answer (score 1):

> http://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-etymology.php?zi=%E5%85%A5
>
> (象形) Pictographic. Picture of the sharp point of an arrow used to pierce something.

~

> http://www.chineseetymology.org/CharacterEtymology.aspx?characterInput=%E5%85%A5
>
> Primitive pictograph 入. An open tent door. Meaning enter.

~

> http://www.vividict.com/wordinfo.aspx?id=3197
>
> 字源解说
>
> 入，甲骨文像盒盖向下，表示收存物品，加盖封藏。造字本义：收存物品，加盖封藏。
>
> (入 in oracle looked like a lid facing down to represent "to store items in" , or 'seal something with a lid' .  "Enter" was an extended meaning.
>
> The original meaning of the word: the storage of items, stamped sealed.)
>
> 金文承续甲骨文字形。有的金文形似屋“宀”。
>
> (金文 inherited Oracle shape. Some 金文 of 入 looked like "house")
>
> *that may had been the origin of 'An open tent door' etymology*

After studied the references, my conclusion is the earliest pictographic of 入 resembled a lid facing down.  Then evolved into 'open tent' shape.

The 'arrow' representing 'enter' (入) etymology is likely an later  interpretation. (*depend on how early 'arrow head' was invented, it might had been developed concurrently with 'lid'  for the meaning of 入*)